# How to Use the Media attribute for handhelds of the HTML Link tag?

Tags: html, mobile

I currently have the following in my HTML document.

```
<link REL=StyleSheet HREF="/stylesheets/home.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
<link REL=StyleSheet HREF="/stylesheets/homedark.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=handheld>
```

However, nothing changes on a handheld device (my Android phone). Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is it just not this simple?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to use more advanced *media queries*, such as those that target `screen size`

So something more like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/homedark.css" type="text/css" 
    media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">
```

Inside your stylesheet, it would be something like this

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    //Your styles here
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Simple JS device detection might be helpful:

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || 
    navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || 
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || 
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)){
     // link to stylesheet
}
```

An even better thing to do is use some sort of combo... media queries & device / feature detection.

This is a good overview: http://www.csskarma.com/presentations/cssla/slides/mobile_media_touch.pdf (WARNING: pdf file)

Answer (score 1):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) the handheld media type is deprecated anyway.  You will need to use media queries to accomplish what you want.

Too bad there isn't a media type for "phone".  The ability to dial a number is really the most distinctive difference.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your phone doesn't consider itself a handheld according to whatever criteria the W3C uses for that term. Modern mobile browsers aren't that different from a full-blown desktop one and are nowhere near as limited as the original (useless) WAP browsers in dumbphones were. There's usually no real need to output a "handheld" type as the phone browser is better at deciding what/how to show content than the site is.

Comment: So what is a better way to do this? Assume my site will be displayed well on a mobile device (it displays alright, but I have a mobile-specific stylesheet written up that'll make it really easy to browse) or use a different method to select stylesheets?

Comment: Most sites use browser sniffing to figure out what css to serve up. You could also do some rough decisions based on source IP - which'd catch mobile users using cellular data (but not smartphone users on wifi).

Comment: Twitter bootstrap uses the width of the device to see what device the user is using. You can check this out: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive